# How can you tell if an Xnode is of XElement type?

Tags: c#, linq

I am running a linQ query from a list of all Descendant Nodes element. I would like to differentiate and filter out the XElement types. How can I do this besides using a .toString() and comparing it with "Element"?

```
 string filename = @"C:\MyFiles\Programming\XML\MobileResponse2.xml";
        var elem = XElement.Load(filename);
        var query = from c in elem.DescendantNodes()
                    where c.NodeType.ToString() == "Element"  
                    select c;
```

Note: I can use elem.Descendant or elem.elements() but I am trying to figure out how to check in the "Where" clause if an object is of a certain type?

I was going to go with

```
where c.NodeType.ToString() is XElement
```

but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just noticed your "Note" ;)

```
var query = elem.DescendantNodes().Where (w => w is XElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string filename = @"C:\MyFiles\Programming\XML\MobileResponse2.xml";
var elem = XElement.Load(filename);
var query = from c in elem.DescendantNodes()
            where c is XElement
            select c;
```